# How do I connect my NATS docker image to my k8s NATS cluster?

Tags: url, kubernetes, connection, nats.io

I deployed NATS to my kubernetes cluster, and the nats-box image in my cluster (installed alongside my NATS image vis helm) can apparently connect to it, but I can't seem to get my own microservice to connect to it.  How is nats-box successful, but my own microservice is not?

> helm install my-nats nats/nats

installs NATS with statefulset called "my-nats" and a service called "my-nats":

```
my-nats     ClusterIP  None   <none> 

4222/TCP,6222/TCP,8222/TCP,7777/TCP,7422/TCP,7522/TCP
```

But my test app uses stdin to accept a url input and tries to connect to "my-nats" and yet it fails:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("=>");
        string url = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Connecting to {url}");
        try
        {
            using (IConnection pubConnection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Connected to {url}!");
            }
        }
        catch (NATSNoServersException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"No Server found for url, '{url}'!");
            return;
        }
 ...
```

> docker run -it testapp

=>my-nats

Connecting to my-nats

No Server found for url, 'my-nats'!

How can I get my microservice to connect to my "my-nats" cluster just like nats-box does?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect from local(microservice) to nats in your cluster(K8s running in your machine).
if so you might need to do a port forward of the nats from your cluster then use http://localhost:4222 as the url for your microservice nats connection url.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of running your application and connecting to the NATS server (or any other).

### Your app runs locally

You could use `kubectl port-forward -n nats svc/my-nats 4222:4222` to forward the nats port 4222 to `localhost:4222`.
Then your application needs to connect to `localhost:4222` instead of `my-nats`.

### Your app runs on the same k8s cluster as the NATS server does.

In this case, you need to check if you deployed your application in the same namespace as your NATS server. If so, your app should be able to connect to `my-nats`. If not, you need to connect to the service using this schema `<name of service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` or at least `my-nats.<your-namespace>`.